JSONの配列構造について
JSONの配列構造について質問です。
例えば以下のように定義されている場合、Test[0] の結果は "name:"tarou","age":"30" となるでしょうか。
"Test": [
  {
    "name:"tarou",
    "age":"30"
  }
  {
    "name":"jirou",
    "age":"20"
  }
]


「Test[0]の結果」って何ですか？　何の話をしてますか？　JSON 文字列を JavaScript オブジェクトにデシリアライズして何かするんですか？

「例えば」の下に書いたものは JSON として正しくありません。直してください


Test[0]の結果は"name:"tarou","age":"30"となるでしょうか。

どのような言語のどのようなJSONパーザを使っているかに依存する話ですが、一般的には「nameプロパティとageプロパティを持ったオブジェクト」になると思います。JavaScript 的に書くと { name:"tarou", age:"30" } です。

質問の「Test[0]の結果」の意味が不明、かつ、例が JSON として正しくないですが・・・
JSON 文字列を JavaScript オブジェクトにデシリアライズして何かするのであろうと想像して回答します。

Test[0] の結果は "name:"tarou","age":"30" となるでしょうか。

以下は質問の JSON 文字列（訂正したもの）を JavaScript で扱ったものですが、これとその結果を見たら質問の答えが分かるのではないかと思います。分からなかったら、何が分からないかを下のコメント欄に書いてください。
// JSON 文字列（正しい JSON に訂正）
let json = '{"Test":[{"name":"tarou","age":"30"},{"name":"jirou","age":"20"}]}';

// 上の JSON 文字列を JavaScript オブジェクトにデシリアライズ
let obj = JSON.parse(json);

// 結果を Console に表示
console.log(obj);
console.log(obj.Test[0]);
console.log(obj.Test[0].name);

// obj.Test[0] を JSON 文字列にシリアライズ
let test0json = JSON.stringify(obj.Test[0]);

// 結果を Console に表示
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj.Test[0]));

結果

